# Company-mode in groovy-mode: How to get completions other than lowercase?

Tags: company-mode, completion

I'm using `groovy-mode` with `company-mode` enabled; completion suggestions are in all lowercase. Whereas, in `java-mode` -- a built-in package, and others such as `python-mode`, `ruby-mode`, company is giving camelCase suggestions.

How can we get similar behaviour in `groovy-mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `company-dabbrev` as the backend of `groovy-mode`, the problem may be solved by

```
(setq company-dabbrev-downcase nil)
```

This command keeps the candidate as it is.
If you think that ignoring case is better when the candidates is collected, you
should add

```
(setq company-dabbrev-ignore-case t)
```

Don't set `company-dabbrev-ignore-case` `'keep-prefix'` since only prefix is
kept as it is. Writing my answer, I refer to
[this](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/60) on github page.

Comment: If this command does not work well, I want to know your backend on `groovy-mode`. You probably use the different backend on `groovy-mode`. So tell the variable `company-backends`.